# How to show up a notification if user haven't used the app for a while (1 week)?

Tags: android, notifications

I want to show a reminder notification if the user haven't used my app for a while. I know how to show a notification with the alarmmanager, my problem is, how can i know if user didn't open the app for a while. I can set the alarm when user opens the app, but then there will be multiple alarms.

Comment: And you don't know how to clear the alarm? Is this not documented? Regardless, I would recommend against that... naggy apps are quickly uninstalled.

Comment: store the last usage date for example with sharedPreferences. Whenever your desired activity gets resumed, read the last usage and get the difference. If the difference is high enough, show your toast message or what ever message you like

Comment: 323go, I know how to clear alarm but it does not work as intended. 

@Michael thank you for your answer i think your method solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your Alarm's [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html), pass the flag : `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

You won't get in a situation where you have multiple alarms as the existing one will be updated.